# Eclipse - stack overflow errors

Tags: php, eclipse, stack-overflow

Since some time I'm having problems with Eclipse. When opening any file with a class which extends one specified class (`Presenter`), an error occurs:

[Multiple problems have occurred http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/9678/screeneclipseproblems.png](http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/9678/screeneclipseproblems.png)
[Internal Error http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/5131/screeneclipseproblemspr.png](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/5131/screeneclipseproblemspr.png)

I've noted, that problems occurs only when loading the mentioned class - `Presenter`.
When I delete "extends Presenter" or when I delete the file, which contains class `Presenter`, the problems dissappear.

Class `Presenter` is part of the PHP framework [Nette](http://nette.org/en/), so you can see the contents of this class here:
http://api.nette.org/1.0/__filesource/fsource_Nette-Application__ApplicationPresenter.php.html

I can provide contents of LOG files, if that may help, but those are large (over 1 MiB).

Comment: Stack Overflow errors? I'm not sure we can help those here... :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exact version of Eclipse and PDT are you using?

There was a bug last month about that kind of error: **[bug 316876](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=316876)**, but it appears to be fixed in `PDT-2.2.0.v20100616`.

Check also your `eclipse.ini` like, for instance, [this ones (depending on your eclipse version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse).

Comment: Increasing stack size unfortunately doesn't help...
Here's part of my eclipse.ini:

    -vmargs
    -Xms128m
    -Xmx1024m
    -Xss1m

I have PDT 2.2.0.v20100519, but I can't find any way to update PDT to mentioned version...
Eclise says there's no updates... :)

http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/9288/screeneclipseupdate.png

Comment: @Radek: try using the exact settings I mention in the eclipse.ini link. Are you using Eclipse Helios 3.6? Even if Eclipse says there is not update, you could try unzipping the [latest update site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/pdt/downloads/drops/2.1.2/R200908310846/pdt-Update-2.1.2.zip) from the [PDT downloads page](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/), and see if a more recent version helps.

Comment: I've tried that multiple times, but the fact is, I cant find the right version you mentioned (2.2.0.v20100616).
I've tried to download last 2.2.0 Maintenance build on http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/ , which should contains the bugfix, but in fact the ZIP contains some different version:
http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/9495/eclisenotupdate.png - 2.2.0.v20100519, not 20100616...

Comment: @Radek: strange: I suppose they haven't released that exact version yet.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. Here is the way to fixe it:

1. First goto [workbench_directory]/.metadata/.plugins/ - remove the folder named "eclipse.org.core.resources" and keep a copy of it.
2. Now go to the eclipse directory using CommandPrompt(Windows) or Terminal(in linux,mac) 
   write the command $ eclipse -clean  ---> this will start your eclipse application.
3. Now close the eclipse application and restore the "eclipse.org.core.resources" folder that you removed in the First step.

That's it! You won't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase VM stacksize and check. But a better solution would be to work out how to avoid recursing so much.

Add the flag `-Xss1024k` in the VM arguments for starting Eclipse (in eclipse.ini file in your Eclipse installation folder).

You can also increase the stack size in MB, by using `-Xss1m` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Eclipse Indigo. I've adding the following to my eclipse.ini file as I didn't have them in there.

-Xmx1024m
-Xss1m

I haven't been able to salvage my Eclipse installation. The Error logs in Eclipse pertain to issues with the OSGI and Team plugin. I can try uninstalling these.